# Trying to upgrade some older code to 0.18

Tags: elm

This is the last error I am trying to fix. It was originally

```
Task.perform HTTPError SetPeople (Http.get (Json.list decodePerson) peopleUrl)
```

but I have got done to what you see below. I think I need to use attempt instead of perform but then that deals with `Result` which I think would take a larger refactor. i don't know I'm brand new.

```
The 2nd argument to function `perform` is causing a mismatch.

87|             Task.perform SetPeople (Http.get peopleUrl (Json.list decodePerson)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `perform` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    Task.Task Never (List Person)

But it is:

    Http.Request (List Person)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 0.18 version of HTTP requests bypasses the direct need for tasks and allows you to create `Cmd msg` directly. Your code can probably be rewritten like this:

```elm
Http.get peopleUrl (Json.list decodePerson)
    |> Http.send SetPeople
```

This assumes that your `Msg` is now defined as

```
type Msg
    = ...
    | SetPeople (Result Http.Error (List Person))
```

Read more about [the Http package here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/latest).

Comment: So i changed it to `Http.get peopleUrl (Json.list decodePerson)
                |> Http.send SetPeople` which is what i think you meant and have my message like you sent but I get :
Function `send` is expecting the argument to be:

    `Result Http.Error a -> msg`

But it is:

    `Http.Error -> List Person -> Msg`

Comment: Ahhhh i got it the msg should be `SetPeople (Result Http.Error (List))`

Comment: Whoops, I missed the decoder parameter in my answer! I've updated it and made the second bit more explicit